# Trying to import fractions but it's giving me a syntax error

Tags: python

I have downloaded/installed the quicktions library into Thonny and I've tried

```
import fraction
import Fractions
from fractions import Fraction
from fractions import *
```

It just keeps saying (in the shell)

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\(my name)\Desktop\yy.py", line 3
print Fraction(10,6)
```

I have a computer science final project due tonight and I've been stuck on this problem for 3 or 4 hours, and it's due in 5 hours. I have to make a calculator to calculate a side of a triangle using sin and it's very important I am able to use fractions, I need help I'm new to coding thank you

Comment: Are you using Python 3?  `print` was changed to be a function, but it looks like you're using code written for an older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, could it be that you are using Python 3 and are trying to use print using the Python 2 style? Try changing that line to:

```
from fractions import Fraction

print(Fraction(10, 6))
```

Comment: @CristiFati Thank you, my first post here, had trouble with all the formatting, fixed it

Comment: Sure. At first, I downvoted the answer for being incorrect, then I retracted the downvote.